# Selecting CSS clas based on ID AND Class?

Tags: html, css

I have 5 menu items, and a background that is repeated on the image 5 times which uses `background-position:0 -60px` to give the "selected" effect.

To select which part of the image is used, I am trying to use a class with a number, but it doesn't seem to work.

(Sorry this was hard for me to explain)

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/G4mLB/

**HTML:** (Class=3 is suppose to be the 3rd page)

```
<div id="menu" class="3">
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:104px;
    left:0;
    height:60px;
    width:523px;
    background-image:url('http://kitoit.com/new/img/menu-buttons.png');
}
#menu .1 {
    background-position:0 0px;
}
#menu .2 {
    background-position:0 -60px;
}
#menu .3 {
    background-position:0 -120px;
}
#menu .4 {
    background-position:0 -180px;
}
#menu .5 {
    background-position:0 -240px;
}
```

Comment: That should work, but what's wrong with `class="menux"` for each `x`?

Comment: Because I would have to add everything under #menu to each one.

Comment: @OllieFord Also, in the fiddle you will see its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have invalid class names, they can't start with number - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors), especialy:

> Basically, a name must begin with an underscore (_), a dash (-), or a letter(a–z), followed by any number of dashes, underscores, letters, or numbers.

To fix your issue, name them for example `itemX` and use it like this (note that i remove space between `#menu` and `.item3`):

```
#menu.item3 {
   background-position:0 -120px;
}
...
<div id="menu" class="item3">
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGe4C/) with working example.

Comment: Thank you I see now. Also need to remove the space between #menu and .item3

Comment: Yes, I add this to my answer right now, just refresh it.

Comment: @Joey if my answer help you, consider to mark it and close this question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of number us letter and change css like this

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/G4mLB/14/

> css

```
#menu {
  position:absolute;
  top:104px;
  left:0;
  height:60px;
  width:525px;
  background-image:url('http://kitoit.com/new/img/menu-buttons.png');
}

div.one {
 background-position:0 0px;
}
div.two {
 background-position:0 -60px;
}

div.thr {
 background-position:0 -120px;
}

div.four {
background-position:0 -180px;
}

div.five {
background-position:0 -240px;
}
```